# .NET 6 Angular - Controllers Only Default "WeatherForecastController" works, all others return 404 not found

Tags: c#, angular, api, controller, .net-6.0

With a mostly default .NET 6 Website (with Angular) I'm trying to add some controllers but any I add don't seem to work, they all return 404 (plus some HTML).

However the default controller "WeatherForecastController" works, even after changing the content to be identical to a new controller.

[image]

My 2 controllers are completely identical aside from the name:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace TestWebsite.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public string Get()
        {
            return "OK";
        }
    }
}
```

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace TestWebsite.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class OtherController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public string Get()
        {
            return "OK";
        }
    }
}
```

"WeatherForecastController" works:
[image]

"OtherController" returns 404:
[image]

Program.cs (literally unedited):

```
public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

            builder.Services
                .AddControllersWithViews();

            var app = builder.Build();

            // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
            if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
            {
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseRouting();

            app.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
            );

            app.MapFallbackToFile("index.html");

            app.Run();
        }
    }
```

Edit: I have just found that both controllers work as expected when I call via http and the http port, so it is only https having this issue.

Comment: maybe missing `app.MapControllers();` after setting your `app.MapControllerRoute()`

Comment: @EricRobinson No difference, have just found it works normally under http however, so it's just https having this issue for some reason

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was the proxy.conf.js under ClientApp:

```
const { env } = require('process');

const target = env.ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT ? `https://localhost:${env.ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT}` :
  env.ASPNETCORE_URLS ? env.ASPNETCORE_URLS.split(';')[0] : 'http://localhost:25215';

const PROXY_CONFIG = [
  {
    context: [
      "/weatherforecast",
   ],
    target: target,
    secure: false,
    headers: {
      Connection: 'Keep-Alive'
    }
  }
]

module.exports = PROXY_CONFIG;
```

By default it just has `/weatherforecast` meaning the angular server only forwards those requests to .NET, I changed it to `/api/**` and changed my controller `[Route]` to `api/[controller]` and all is now working as expected.